# Change how GET url is displayed

Tags: django, django-urls

Summary: If I search 'apple', the url will be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/search_results?csrfmiddlewaretoken=rlUwb5Ju3Xr585FarH5eAGQJtpog83hqW4wRysbsMWM6eiO3prcKRONY28N118gR&query=apple&button=` and I just want to know if there is a way to change this to something cleaner like `127.0.0.1:8000/search_results/apple`?
Here is my code:

urls.py

```
path('search_results', views.search_results, name = 'search_results'),
```

html:

```
 <form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="GET">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <input  name = 'query' type = 'text'/>
     <button type="submit" name="button">Search</button>

 </form>
```

and views.py:

```
def search_results(request):
    query =request.GET.get('query')
    return HttpResponse(query)
```

I had tried to change these 3 lines in their respective files:

```
`path('search_results/<str:query>')`, # thought this would achieve /search_results/apple url
```

```
<form action="{% url 'search_results' 'query' %}" method="GET">
```

```
def search_results(request, query):
```

but this did not work. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: The GET parameters are encoded in the querystring. The querystring is *not* part of the path. There is thus no way to encode this that way. But you can indeed make a "redirect view" that moves it to the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GET parameters are encoded in the [*query string* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Querystring). The query string is *not* part of the path. There is thus no way to encode this that way. But you can indeed make a "redirect view" that moves it to the path.

You can change the redirect to:

```
# app/views.py

from django.shortcuts import redirect

def search_redir(request):
    query =request.GET.get('query')
    return redirect('search_results', query=query)

def search_results(request, query):
    # …
    pass
```

In your `urls.py`, you then define two views: one that will "catch" the initial GET request with the querystring, and one where you move the query to the path:

```
# app/urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('search_results/', views.search_redir, name='search_redir'),
    path('search_results/<str:query>/', views.search_results, name='search_results'),
]
```

In your form however, you still use the *redirect view*. Note that since you perform a GET request you do not need to use the `{% csrf_token %}`:

```
<form action="{% url 'search_redir' %}" method="GET">
    <input  name="query" type ="text"/>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Would having to call two views like this have a large impact on efficiency/cost at scale? I went to see if Google had a clean URL and noticed they leave the very ugly original URL intact.

Comment: Though interesting from a user perspective I've never noticed or cared until I had this question

Comment: @user3131132: the redirect does not require any database access or anything. So likely it is not that costly no. It will make two requests, so it will take a bit longer to fetch the results, but that is mainly due to network delays.